# How can I print the contents of a js file to the screen from a URL?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, mootools

I have an application that will check if a javascript file exists on our CDN and I would like to display the contents of that file in the browser window.  I have all the nuts and bolts figured out, I just need to display the contents of the javascript file when I put in the URL where it exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the problem? Publish the file and if you don`t generate it with something on the server side and adding headers, it should be readable rather then downloadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can output a javascript file to a webpage by just making sure any html elements are escaped. You can use the htmleditformat() function to do this when you output the value.

For example:

```
<cfhttp url="#jsurl#"  />
<cfoutput><pre>#htmleditformat(cfhttp.filecontent)#</pre></cfoutput>
```

Other options just using the js address directly are to 1) link to the js file if you just want to be able to see it in the window, or 2) show the js file in an iframe

Comment: htmlCodeFormat() includes the `<pre>` tags intrinsically.

Comment: I don't believe so as htmleditformat() is primarily used in my experience during form value output. For example <input value="#htmleditformat(value)#"... etc. In that situation it would not make sense. <pre> is specific html tag that preserves spacing and displays content in a monospaced font if I'm not mistaken, which are both important for viewing code. There is actually a <code> tag which I have never used but might be useful as well.

Comment: Quoting from the docs: "The only difference between [HTMLCodeFormat] and HTMLEditFormat is that HTMLEditFormat does not surround the text in an HTML pre tag."

Comment: I misread your comment and thought you said htmlEDITformat. You are correct.

Comment: This solution worked quite well.   Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking:

1. "I need to open a javascript file in a web browser"
   A. this is OS dependant, you call the binary that's registered for .htm files with parameters pointing it's initial destination to that .js file.
2. "I have a web app and want to dynamically display the contents of remote files formatted as text"
   A. Use a  block and fill it with GetWebResourceUrl().
3. "I am writing a standalone app and want to display remote files as text"
   A. If you are writing a standalone, why do you want to display the contents of a js file via a browser? Use your local API, or launch the default text viewer with a local temp copy.